# What is the use of Doctrine setter on many-to-many relations?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, persistence, many-to-many

Today I met some unexpected behavior on doctrine (1.2).

## Situation

I've a `Document` class, and an `Anomaly` class. A `Document` can have many `Anomalies`, and an `Anomaly` can be found on many `Documents`.

```
#schema.yml

Document:
  columns:
    id:       { type: integer(12), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    scan_id:  { type: integer(10), notnull: true }
    name:     { type: string(100), notnull: true }

Anomaly:
  columns:
    id:     { type: integer(5), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    label:  { type: string(200) }
    value:  { type: integer(6), notnull: true, unique: true }
  relations:
    Documents:
      class:        Document
      refClass:     DocumentAnomaly
      local:        anomaly_id
      foreign:      document_id
      foreignAlias: Anomalies

DocumentAnomaly:
  columns:
    document_id:  { type: integer(12), primary: true }
    anomaly_id:   { type: integer(5), primary: true }
  relations:
    Anomaly:  { local: anomaly_id, foreign: id }
    Document: { local: document_id, foreign: id }
```

## Problem

I want to instantiate a new `Document`, assign it's attributes some value, and assign him a list of `Anomaly`.

```
#sample code

$anomalies = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Anomaly')->getSomeAnomalies(); //returns a valid and non empty Doctrine_Collection of Anomalies

$document = new Document();
$document->setName('test')
  ->setScanId(3574)
  ->setAnomalies($anomalies)
  ->save();

echo $document->getId(); // "1"
print_r($document->getDocumentAnomaly()->toArray(); // empty array
print_r($document->getAnomalies()->toArray(); //correct array, listing anomalies from "->getSomeAnomalies()"
```

**Consequences:** the `Document` is persisted in the database, but not the link to its `Anomalies` (`DocumentAnomaly` table/objects).

## Workaround

```
$anomalies = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Anomaly')->getSomeAnomalies();

$document = new Document();
$document->setName('test')
  ->setScanId(3574)
  ->setAnomalies($anomalies)
  ->save();

foreach ($anomalies as $anomaly)
{
  $documentAnomaly = new DocumentAnomaly();
  $documentAnomaly->setDocument($document)
    ->setAnomaly($anomaly);
  $documentAnomaly->save();
}

//Document is persisted, *and it's DocumentAnomalies too*.
```

## My question

What is the use of the `$document->setAnomalies()` method ? Is there any ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are passing the wrong parameters. Check out this: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/working-with-models%3Amany-to-many-relations/en

Comment: +1, you should check the type of value returned by `->getSomeAnomalies()` (I don't think you can directly pass a `Doctrine_Collection`, but rather an array of records or something like that).

Comment: @NiKo: exception is thrown when trying to pass an array of `Doctrine_Record`, as a `Doctrine_collection` is expected.
@edem: thank you for the link, I found a better workaround in it, but still, what is the purpose of the `setAnomalies()` method ?

Comment: Why did you write `setAnomalie` without 's' in your code?

Comment: @greg0ire: typo when writing the question. I edited it, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Document->Anomalies->add($Anomaly);

Comment: Thank you, in fact I didn't know you could add/remove using that syntax. But still, what is the use of `setAnomalies()` ?

Comment: I accept this answer because I learner something from it, even if it doesn't really answer the question.